# Starting rep boost for authors/employees

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

Is there any way to give software authors or company employees a 50 point rep boost so they can comment anywhere from the start? Similar to that 100 point bonus to other SE sites when you reach a certain rep level on one.

I've seen a few cases where either the author of a script/tool/software or someone working at a company in support/help desk or whatever want to help out and post in reply to a question about their product, but it's either a comment and not an answer or they need more clarification or something. It has come up a few times in the past couple of months.

I know we have bounties, and I guess you could place a bounty on the question, manually award it to their answer, then delete/convert to comment, but that seems roundabout.

This also might be a feature request or something for Meta, but I wanted to post here in case mods or more experienced users might know of a current workaround or alternative.

Comment: How do we validate or vet developers/authors/company employees? a 50 rep is not huge amount to ask, there are already employees of companies answering questions without the  jump start rep.

Comment: @Mapperz I was thinking of it as less an application type of thing and more a mod type of thing. Cases where an answer/comment states 'I'm the author of' or 'disclaimer I work for'. I guess I'm just an optimist that it wouldn't be abused or need to be validated, or at the same time more a if you have to ask no, but if notices because of flags and such it could just be quietly done. I agree it's not a huge amount, but I know it took me a few weeks to get. Heck, even one solid answer could do it. I've just seen three or four examples lately of comments posted as answers from such people.

Comment: We mods have no powers to award bonuses, and speaking for myself, no desire to ever have them.

Comment: I feel that any active developer will have a stackoveflow account; Once they link both these, they automatically get a 100 rep bonus. So I don't see the need for this.

Comment: This one's in negative territory from our community so I've set it to [meta-tag:status-declined].  There's always [meta.se] but I think you'll find that community quite harsh on any idea they think won't fly.

Answer (score 8):

Reputation is given to its users by the Stack Exchange network based on their interactions on its sites so I would not expect to see any request to have someone not already interacting with us awarded such a bonus succeed.

I think the best option to help anyone who would appear to be a worthy recipient of such a bonus is to make them aware of [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Nobody has been seeking it. This is more of an observational thing. And while that meta article certainly applies in general, I'm not talking about broad spectrum application here, just a very specific and small group of people in relation to specific flags that have come up for review lately. I suppose instead I could just not flag such 'answers' and add a comment to the effect of 'go ahead and make assumptions to provide an actual answer, you can always edit it if your assumptions are wrong'.

Comment: Suggesting to this user category that it may be best to make assumptions to elevate what might have been a comment into an answer seems like a good way forward.